# JavaScript regexp, not getting all matches, what am I missing here?

Tags: javascript, regex

Let's say for example I have this simple string

```
let str = '5+81+3+16+42'
```

Now if I want to capture each plus sign with both numbers around it.

My attempt was as follows:

```
let matches = str.match(/\d+\+\d+/g);
```

What I got with that is:

```
['5+81', '3+16']
```

Why is it not matching the cases between?

```
['5+81', '81+3', '3+16', '16+42']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex has to fulfill the whole pattern which is `\d+\+\d+`. It will first match `5+81`, then the next character is a `+` which the pattern can not match because it should start with a digit. Then it can match `3+16` but it can not match the following `+42` anymore given you `['5+81', '3+16']` as the matches.

Without a regex, you might use [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and a for loop and check if the next value exists in the `parts` array:

```js
let str = '5+81+3+16+42'
let parts = str.split('+');
for (let i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
  if (undefined !== parts[i + 1]) {
    console.log(parts[i] + '+' + parts[i + 1]);
  }
}
```

When using more a recent version of Chrome which supports lookbehinds, you might use lookarounds with capturing groups:

`(?<=(\d+))(\+)(?=(\d+))`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EPtUNH/1)

```js
const regex = /(?<=(\d+))(\+)(?=(\d+))/g;
const str = `5+81+3+16+42`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }
  console.log(m[1] + m[2] + m[3]);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When the regular expression engine completes one iteration of a match, it "consumes" the characters from the source string. The first match of `5+81` leaves the starting point for the next match at the `+` sign after `81`, so the next match for the expression begins at the `3`.

Comment: just curious i am new to regex i know the basics very well. i heard about recursive regex ? can we do this in JS ?

Comment: No, JavaScript has no recursive expression support.

Answer (score 2):

Split string by `+` delimiter and use `.reduce()` to create new array contain target result.

```js
let str = '5+81+3+16+42';
let arr = str.split('+').reduce((tot, num, i, arr) => { 
  i+1 < arr.length ? tot.push(num+"+"+arr[i+1]) : '';
  return tot; 
}, []);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Using plus sign was just an example, it could mix of signs, my mistake I've should made it clear

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) without making things complex with regex.

```js
let str = '5+81+3+16+42';
const array = str.split('+');

const splited = []
array.reduce((a, b) => {
  splited.push(a+'+'+b)
  return b
})

console.log(splited);
```

Comment: Using plus sign was just an example, it could mix of signs, my mistake I've should made it clear